# How to configure GRUB2 to boot from sdcard

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a Intel Compute Stick Ubuntu Version and I have installed on external sdcard (mmcblk1) xubuntu 14.04.
Now I want be able to start xubuntu from grub2 installed in mmcblk0.

Bios not supports boot from sdcard.

I haven't find a clear tutorial, please help me.

Comment: I resolved my issue running boot-repair from live cd and selecting Xubuntu as default so.